# Is it possible to apply media queries style with random window size using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

Is it possible to apply media queries style with random window size using javascript ?

I have 5 buttons, I need to switch using javascript to another css styles using the media queries definition in my css stylesheet.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: please provide more specifics about what you mean by `switch`. Can change classes easily if that helps

Comment: So you want to make it think your media matches one of the other queries?

Comment: Why do you need js? Can't you just change the syles with media queries alone? And why would you need random window size?

Comment: @MichałMusialik I suspect he wants a button that says "Show what the page looks like on a tablet"

Comment: @barman is right, I need a button for that :)

Comment: @BigDong if you want something like what Barmar said, I think you can just try resizing the window yourself, in script you can just set the window's size. Of course that way we can just test some options in @media rule, such as `max-width` (not `max-device-width`), orientation, ...

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is put each media query in a different css file. Then use js to swap them.

Comment: It's seems to be a nice alternative, it means it is not possible to do it with a button "show what the page looks like on a device" ? It would be nice to also add some animation transition, instead than just swapping css classes.